# What does it mean for Euler's zeta function identity to be "formal"?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, measure-theory, terminology, riemann-zeta

A book I'm reading is asking me to prove the "formal [Euler's] identity for the zeta function". I'm unsure of what the word "formal" means here, as I thought it meant to prove the identity in the algebraic sense (similarly to e.g. formal power series), but I don't see an obvious algebraic formalization of the infinite sum $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$.

I looked it up online and found only an imprecise "algebraic" proof (essentially Euler's original proof which has some questionable manipulations of infinite sums) and a standard analytic bounding argument.

Comment: There is the ring of formal Dirichlet series where we don't look at convergence / evaluation at $s\in \Bbb{C}$. Instead we consider the $n^{-s}$ as formal variables satisfying $n^{-s}m^{-s}=(nm)^{-s}$. The Euler product makes sense in this ring.

Comment: Here is a proof https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/the-extended-riemann-hypothesis-and-ramanujans-sum/#toggle-id-2 and it involves some manipulations on infinite sums and infinite products. I guess that these manipulations are referenced as "formal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "formal" there just means "ignoring convergence issues". That's analogous to formal power series (and the notion of of a formal group). There is no need to try to develop a rigorous concept of formal Dirichlet series to solve your problem: just do the calculation without worrying about justifying the rearrangement of terms. That is a "formal calculation".

Elsewhere in math, "formal" can mean "quite rigorous", as in logic: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_(mathematical_logic)). From that point of view, we should be calling formal power series "informal power series". :) But nobody does that.